# Detect mouse movements and clicks in a Skype video window

Tags: c#, windows, mouse, skype

I'm trying to figure out a way for my c# app to detect the mouse movements and clicks in a Skype window that is displaying video call.

I need to detect when the mouse is clicked on the Skype video and then get the coordinates of mouse.

I will also need to detect the current size of the Skype window.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some windows API calls

Things that will be useful:

Skype window size and location

MouseGetPos()

MouseDownEvent

MouseUpEvent

all of those can be achived by making windows API calls.